# PowerApps - Saving Mic Audio into Playable format

Tags: android, ios, audio, sharepoint, powerapps

We're trying to upload playable audio files from PowerApps mic to SharePoint Online list.

I have used the following line:

```
Patch(sharepointlistname, ForAll(Gallery1.AllItems,{Title:Title, VoiceMessage:Audio});
```

The above returns the following results:
 (from Android and iPhone, .aac and .caf links (respectively) to SharePoint List):

```
data/bb788abd-7848-449f-810b-2bd6368dcb19.aac
```

or

```
temp/recording_8BA1187E-158A-469E-9994-F644C6F619D8-1610-000001A0FBF5F1F0.caf
```

It seems impossible to convert these .aac and .caf to .wav or any playable file.

Can someone guide me on this, or maybe let me know where the actual audio files are being saved to from powerapps? The .aac or .caf links are most likely references to a specific location on a local database that is created by PowerApps. Unfortunately, I have not found any information.

Answer (score 0):

aac files and caf files are audio files. They are not just your regular and familiar wav or mp3 files.

Both formats can be played by Quicktime.

You can find a list of all the programs that can play those formats here:

http://extension.nirsoft.net/caf

http://extension.nirsoft.net/aac

Comment: The problem is that when we are saving the mic audio from power apps to a sharepoint list we are getting a text value: http://imgur.com/a/iMXJB.
The first one was created from PowerApps running on a pc, the second from an Android phone and the third from an iOS phone.

We would like to find a way to convert these strings into playable audio files. Is what we're getting a file name? Is it a reference to a database? If yes, where do we find the file/db?